# Number of lines in each revision

Tags: svn

I am trying to get the number of lines in each revision of a particular file in the subversion repository. I know `svn log filename.txt` returns the number of lines changed for each version. I want the actual number of lines.

Comment: I can't think of a native SVN command that would do this, but you could use [`svn cat`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.cat.html) to get the contents of a file at a particular revision and then grep it

Answer (score 1):

`svn diff -c myrev` outputs the diff introduced by `myrev` revision. This is the maximum information you can get from the machine without applying heuristics.

If you need the number of added lines, post process the output with `|egrep '^\+'|wc -l`, etc.

[statsvn](http://www.statsvn.org/) is a SVN history analysis software written in Java which you can use for inspiration (or as a reference while testing).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following function:

```
function revLineStats() { # <file or url>
  local file=${1}
  for rev in $(svn log "${file}"  |awk '/^r[[:digit:]]+ \|/{print substr($1,2);}'|sort -g)
  do
    printf "%5i : %5i\n"  ${rev} $(svn cat -r ${rev} "${file}" |wc -l)
  done
}
```